# How to protect PHP scripts which are used with iOS app

Tags: php, ios

How can I protect PHP scripts which are used with iOS app?

I have an application that is using Apache/PHP server to get and set some values via POST queries. These scripts are reachable in internet by its public address by anyone. How to determine in script that query is from my application? Because if somebody knows what post data I send, he can try to make query and it will be okay without protection.

Comment: @Anand K You are changing the question by adding the ssl tag, the post has no mention of SSL. The question seems to basically be about authentication.

Comment: @zaph I think Mike want to protect her PHP scripts, thats why I add ssl tag.

Comment: The php scripts are on the server, they are executed on the server, they are never sent to the iOS device. Protecxting the php scripts is a server security issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for HTTPS instead of HTTP connection.

There are lots of tutorial and stuff over net some are bellows

1. [From apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html)
2. [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/)
3. [Vanjakom](https://vanjakom.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/https-client-for-ios/)
4. [cocoanetics](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/12/nsurlconnection-with-self-signed-certificates/)

Why SSL

1. http://www.gtcomm.net/blog/the-importance-and-advantages-of-ssl-certificates/
2. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/what-is-ssl-and-why-is-it-important
3. https://www.sslshopper.com/why-ssl-the-purpose-of-using-ssl-certificates.html

Read this carefully

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work

Comment: i dont really want to secure data  while its transferring via inet. i want only protect php script from users which want make manual requests to my server. i think set up ssl is very hard for such small project like mine

Comment: @AnandK Just adding links is not really an answer and just suggestion to use https is not sufficient.

Comment: @Mike the user will not see your php script, that is run on the server,the user will just see he data you send. The only way to see the php code is to attack the server directly.

Comment: If you are using SSL then only host ip address is visible when trying to middle man attack, if not using ssl then all you parameters with is values are visible.

Comment: @AnandK Without certificate pinning a proxy such as Charles Proxy can see the entire message sent and received.

Comment: @Anand K -  i clear understand it.i dont want to hide data. i see that some people using extra parameter like hash which only app and php script know the rule to compose it. For example app generate Hash via rule e.g. "34131" and php script test it by the same rule and if value the same - okay.

Comment: @Mike but if an attacker can see the Hash value he can also supply that. You should use https, that is the way the Internet is going. If the attacker can not see the data he can not also use it. But what you have is really an authentication problem.

Comment: In my knowledge there is no other way else SSL. You should go for that, If you want to try that use OpenSSL.

Comment: @zaph "attacker can see the Hash value he can also supply that." - i think i can generate new Hash every time by my own rule and test it in php by the same rule. So if attacker see one value he wont reallly know the rule, so he cant use that.

Comment: If you can supply a different hash value each tine that can not be figured out by an attacker that works. Keep in mind that the haskers are hightly skilled and smarter than you.

Comment: i think that my not very complicated rule will be good barrier against school boy hackers))

Comment: @Mike You are thinking correctly, define who you are trying to protect against!

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTTPS and some kind of token / authentication.
In your PHP script add at the top something like this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['my_token']) || $_POST['my_token'] != 'my_secret_value') {
    die();
}
```

If you don't use HTTPS, someone can sniff your token and use the scripts manually.
Keep in mind that this is not a perfect solution.

Comment: ithink to do like this, but improve it by adding my own rule of generate token. thnx